# NUXT 2 - Dynamically creating a sitemap with data from nuxt axios

Tags: axios, nuxt.js, sitemap

There is such an endpoint. When I send a request, the response is as follows
I am using axios. (When you give FR in the header, FR sitemaps come. When I give EN, EN sitemaps come.)

```
  http://mysite/api/sitemap
```

This is the response I got

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
    <url>
        <loc>https://mysite/tr</loc>
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>

    <url>
        <loc>https://mysite/tr/faq/my-faq-1</loc>
        <priority>0.6</priority>
    </url>
   
    <url>
        <loc>https://mysite/tr/blog/my-blog-1</loc>
        <priority>0.6</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

sitemap.xml ---- sitemap-en.xml ---- sitemap-fr.xml

How can I write the incoming data as a sitemap file?

Answer (score 0):

You must use "@nuxtjs/sitemap" package. (https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org)